# Move to next and previous item by clicking on buttons outside the ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I go to the next item by clicking on the next button and previous by clicking the previous button?

**Repeat to Show Data from Database:**

*idSelectedShipment is the selected div or shipment id*

```
<div ng-repeat="shipment in shipments | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
  <div  ng-click="show_shipment($index,shipment.shipment_id)" ng-class="{selected_trip: shipment.shipment_id == idSelectedShipment}">
     <div> From {{shipment.from_location}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Next and Previous Buttons:**

```
<a class="" ng-click="next($event)"  href="#">next</a>
<a class="" ng-click="previous($event)"  href="#">previous</a>
```

I am having trouble in this part. The next button and the previous buttons are outside the ng-repeat and I can not seems to pass the index on the click.

```
 $scope.next= function(index){                    
           [index + 1]
       };
 $scope.previous= function(index){                    
           [index - 1]
       };
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your goal is to render the `selected_trip` class on the "current" repeated element, and your back/next buttons change this?

Based on what you've currently got, what you need to do in your `next` and `back` functions is change the value of `idSelectedShipment` accordingly, but I think that may not be the best way forward.

The tricky part is that your underlying data structure, `shipments`, is sorted for the view. Your controller and the scope outside of your `ngRepeat` block won't be aware of this. For that reason, you can't really use `$index` meaningfully.

What I would recommend is pre-sorting your array in the controller and then keeping track of current index position. Your code would probably look something like the following:

```
function MyController ($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.sortedShipments = $filter('orderBy')($scope.shipments, 'predicate', true);
  $scope.currentShipment = 0;

  $scope.back = function () {
    if ($scope.currentShipment > 0) {
     $scope.currentShipment--;
    }
  };

  $scope.next = function () {
    if ($scope.currentShipment < $scope.sortedShipments.length - 1) {
     $scope.currentShipment++;
    }
  };
}
```

Then change your HTML to...

```
<div ng-repeat="shipment in sortedShipments">
  <div  ng-click="foo()" ng-class="{selected_trip: $index === currentShipment}">
    <div> From {{shipment.from_location}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @cnw for your reply let me try this and i will let you know

Comment: Thanks man i think it is working but i am getting the sorting problem now it is not working.here is my previous sorting code
 $scope.sortType  = 'shipment_id';
          $scope.predicate = 'created_at';
ng-repeat="shipment in shipments | orderBy:predicate:reverse"
          $scope.reverse = false;
$scope.order = function(predicate) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };

Comment: also their is $scope.reverse = false; after the $scope.predicate = 'created_at';
@cmv